# BarChart with Stacked & Group

Tags: javascript

I have prepared google 'bar' chart as below its working properly.how can i change direction of bar form vertical to horizontal ?

I tried to change direction of chart Using  `vAxis: {direction:-1}` but not working.

I tried to get solution from google chart sites but i cant found any other solution for horizontal  bar chart with Stacked & Group. Is there any other way to change direction of Google 'bar' Chart ?

```html
<html>

<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
                ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
                ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
                ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
                ['2017', 1030, 540, 350],
                ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
            ]);

             var options = { 
                 
                 
                isStacked: true,pointSize: 15, 
                vAxis: {
                  viewWindow: {
                    
                    min: 0,
                    
                  }
                },
                
                legend: {
                   position:'bottom',
                    textStyle: {
                        bold: false,
                        fontSize: 12,
                 }

                },
                is3D: true,

                
                
               
                 vAxes: {
                    
                    0:{
                       
                    title: 'value in lac' 
                        },
                  1: {
                      
                    gridlines: {
                      color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    textStyle: {
                      color: 'transparent'
                    }
                  },

                 2: {
                     
                    gridlines: {
                      color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    textStyle: {
                      color: 'transparent'
                    }
                  },
                

                },
                
                


                series: {
                  0: {
                    targetAxisIndex: 0,
                    color:'#2A6DDA'
                  },
                  1: {
                    targetAxisIndex: 1,
                    color:'#FF5733'
                  },
                  2: {
                    targetAxisIndex: 1,
                    color:'#FFC300'
                  },
                  3: {
                    targetAxisIndex: 1,
                    color:'#D3A4FA'
                  },
 
                },
              };
                

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

                chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
                    }
                </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" runat="server" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">


            
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll want to use 'corechart' package instead of 'bar' to access BarChart, see my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how Google charts does it on their examples [page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs)

What you need is to use 'corecharts' instead of 'bars', then change the call to `google.visualization.BarChart()` and you'll get the horizontal bars.

```html
<html>

  <title>Web Page Design</title>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {


          isStacked: true,
          pointSize: 15,
          vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
              min: 0,
            }
          },

          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            textStyle: {
              bold: false,
              fontSize: 12,
            }

          },
          is3D: true,
          vAxes: {
            0: {
              title: 'value in lac'
            },
            1: {
              gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
              },
              textStyle: {
                color: 'transparent'
              }
            },
            2: {
              gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
              },
              textStyle: {
                color: 'transparent'
              }
            },
          },
          series: {
            0: {
              targetAxisIndex: 0,
              color: '#2A6DDA'
            },
            1: {
              targetAxisIndex: 1,
              color: '#FF5733'
            },
            2: {
              targetAxisIndex: 1,
              color: '#FFC300'
            },
            3: {
              targetAxisIndex: 1,
              color: '#D3A4FA'
            },
          },
        };

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_material"));
      chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" runat="server" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">



    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: sir thanks for your response, i would like to elaborate my Question for more clarity. i want to compare expense with profit + sales in this graph. hens as i required cluster /group year wise where one bar show as expense and other bar will be staked for profit and sales.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right then you only need to adjust your array. Have two rows for each year, one that's expense and the other profit and sales. Set the bars to is Stacked true, and then you'll be good to go.

Comment: Happy to help you with whatever else you find that you need, but if this answers your initial question please consider selecting this answer.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your reply, As per your suggestion i changed my array and generated two row for each year but its not looks good as compare to vertical chart stacked with group. is there any option to use `targetAxisIndex` for grouping as i used in vertical chart.